# How to read from device?

Tags: c, alsa

I have a multi-channel interface connected via USB. The documentation states that in order to configure the interface //the API messages should be embedded in the audio stream and sent to a control endpoint that processes those messages. Responses are also transmitted on that endpoint. Messages are sent and received via USB in their entirety; no special formatting//.

Any idea how this could be implemented using alsa. I figured I could use `snd_pcm_open`, `snd_pcm_set_params` and `snd_pcm_writei` to send the API message as raw bytes but how can I read the response?

Comment: An audio stream and a control endpoint are entirely different things. This sounds as if the author of that documentation doesn't understand how USB audio works.

Comment: I think by control endpoint it means the other end of the usb(i.e the audio device) not a control endpoint per see. The documentation doesn't mention a specific driver so it's supposed to work on any host that supports  usb audio 2.0. Initially I was thinking that there would is a tty mounted  and I can send write/read without any specific API but it doesn't seem to be the case. Is there anything that I could try? I must confess that I'm not familiar with usb audio either.

Comment: USB audio has a control endpoint, but it is distinct from the audio streaming endpoint(s). So far, this sounds as if the device is fully USB audio compliant, but I cannot say more while you are keeping the actual documentation secret.